# Gitlab-CI stop stage if multiline script returns an exit code not equal to zero

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is a multiline script block in a gitlab-ci pipeline immediately aborted if a call within these instructions returns an exit code that is not equal to zero?

```
[gitlab-ci.yml]
stage: test
script:
 - export ENVIRONMENTS=$(cat $STAGE-environments.txt)
 - |
   for ENVIRONMENT in ${ENVIRONMENTS}; do
     echo "create tests for stage '$STAGE' and environment '$ENVIRONMENT'"
     create_test $STAGE $ENVIRONMENT
     fill_test $STAGE $ENVIRONMENT
   done
```

The two calls "create_test" and "fill_test" are two bash script functions that return an exit code not equal to zero in the event of an error. If this happens, I want the gitlab-ci stage "test" to stop immediately and mark the job as failed.

Do I have to adapt the multiline script for this?

Comment: Instead of writing multiple line shellscripts with control flow in .gitlab-ci.yml I would suggest to create a shellscript "stage.sh", and run this script in the stage. This is way more comfortable to edit/debug/error check

Comment: The way you have it now should fail (and stop) the *job*, but there isn't a way to stop an entire *stage*. However, if any job in a stage fails, the pipeline will stop at that stage unless you use `allow_failure: true` in your job definition or as a global default.